# leaflet show only india country on map

Tags: leaflet

[image: showing India as center]How to show only india country on the base map? 
How to remove other countries from the base map rendered initailly?

```
this.map = L.map('map', {
  center: [21.0000, 78.0000], // india coordinates 
  zoom: 5,
  zoomControl: true,
  trackResize: true,
});
const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 19,
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
});

tiles.addTo(this.map);
```

Comment: I have set the bounds to india on drag of map it restores to india region

`const maxBounds = L.latLngBounds(
      L.latLng(6.4626999, 68.1097),
      L.latLng(35.513327, 97.39535869999999)
    );
    this.map.setMaxBounds(maxBounds);
    this.map.fitBounds(maxBounds);'

Comment: You can't. Search for alternate basemaps.